# GRUB not responding to keyboard

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, keyboard, bios

I installed Ubuntu 12.4LTS on dual boot with Windows XP on my 7 year old desktop PC 2 months ago.
Everything worked perfectly in both Ubuntu and XP until last week when I removed LibreOffice from Ubuntu and installed OpenOffice 4.0.1. (removal/installation done from Terminal as per Ubuntu online instructions).
At the GRUB menu window, the keyboard is now inoperative, so the system times out and boots Ubuntu (which still works perfectly) but I cannot boot XP.
The keyboard (USB) works perfectly at the BIOS stage of startup, does not work during GRUB, but works again from the Ubuntu login onwards.
I have looked through the Q&As for a solution, the nearest refers to BIOS keyboard setup, but as my keyboard works in BIOS I don't think this is the cause.
I am not sure where the problem might be.  I have looked at grub.cfg, and whilst a newcomer to Linux, cannot see anything obviously corrupt, although I cannot identify which method/module/function call (if any) reads the keyboard.
I was considering reloading GRUB, but if the problem is elsewhere this won't solve it, and might make matters worse.
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of GRUB are you running? Perhaps you could upgrade/reset it in hopes of it fixing whatever GRUB-specific setting that was obviously changed during this process. You should be able to do this from within Ubuntu, or from a bootable USB.

Comment: Thanks for very quick response.  Currently running GRUB 1.99-21ubuntu3.14 (installed 2 months ago).  Will wait until this evening, if no other ideas are forthcoming will try reset or upgrade as you suggest.  Many thanks.  BrianW

Comment: Do you know if there's a specific reason you're not running GRUB 2? "GRUB 2 is the default boot loader and manager for Ubuntu since version 9.10" https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 I don't think it helps if you're running an outdated boot manager, so I would recommend upgrading unless you have a reason to stay on 1.99

Comment: My GRUB 1.99 came with Ubuntu 12.4LTS which I downloaded from the Ubuntu website less than 2 months ago.  I assumed it was the latest version, but from your comment is obviously not.  I will try upgrading this evening and let you know how I get on.  BrianW

Comment: Apparently GRUB 1.98 & 1.99 are both GRUB 2, so I should have latest version. I prepared a boot-repair disk to update or replace GRUB, but now find that my BIOS is no longer booting from CD first (it did when I installed Ubuntu 2 months ago). Today I can't even get into BIOS setup (which I did yesterday & exited without making any changes). PC now boots very quickly to GRUB prompts (skipping all BIOS screens even if Del is held down) then times out to Ubuntu.  Something strange going on which I will get to the bottom of eventually, but could take some time. Will post an update when I get there

Comment: @BrianW: Could you post you last comment as an answer?

Comment: It was really helpful to know it's not a grub issue but a BIOS. Only difference mine was fixed in a USB keyboard enable in BIOS. Strange that this even changed when I changed the boot order from floppy to USB before the HDD. That's strange.

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case I'm working through a KVM switch and the keyboard worked fine with other systems and I was unable to enter my password at the login screen nor choose a different OS to boot from grub. Logging into the guest account and starting Libre Office to test the keyboard resulted in the realization that the ALT-key state was stuck somehow....

Comment: I had an issue with grub (under proxmox - Debian) whereby grub menu would freeze after some key presses. I tried a number of the solutions herein. I tried physical keyboard and iKVM virtual keyboard (physical disconnected). Same issue. What does seem to help in my case is making a single keystroke and then waiting 5 seconds, then the next and so on. Tedious but a workaround nonetheless.

Answer (score 14):

Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS dual boot, GRUB2 reinstalled using boot-repair, wireless USB keyboard, no keyboard recognized on GRUB2 screen resolved.

- BIOS Setup
- Integrated Peripherals
- Legacy USB Support --> [Enabled]

I now have up and down arrow keys on the GRUB2 screen. NumLock is now toggled off at boot time, but NBD.

I'm not sure how to mark it RESOLVED, but since it's not a new thread, I don't think I have the power.

Comment: Oddly, my USB wireless Logitech keyboard start working (but with *very* slow response) when I choose _Legacy USB Support_ = AUTO, not Disable nor Enable. Asus UX303UB, kernel 4.10, I'm pretty sure it was working before.  Default grub setup except for `acpi_osi=`.

Comment: Legacy support was it for me. Thanks.

Comment: I am so glad enabling "Legacy USB" support did the trick.  Couldn't get it working for a whole year lol.

Answer (score 10):

I realise this is quite an old post, but I have had the same problem with a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10.

I found that grub would not respond to my keyboard when connected to a USB3 port, but works fine with legacy USB2.

Comment: It's an old thread, but with recent responses I'm placing this "improvement answer" here so more people can find it: not a naked reply lost at the bottom, in a spot close to the top, in the the thread stream that makes logical and problem-solving sense.

Seemingly unrelated but related key points:

1) I no longer use
   - fast boot, sleep, suspend, or hibernate
in Windows anymore—they don't get along well within the OS nor multi-booting
2) always reboot! (SMH)
3) every OS instance is totally unique, just like each and every other instance.

Detail would be nice, but running out of sp

Answer (score 6):

Although some time has passed and several hints about not working keyboard in grub can be found on the web, i discovered a reason which to consider may help in some cases:

The USB keyboard may be unusuable in grub because another USB device is also plugged in which interferes with grub keyboard usage.

For details in such a case please see https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57010

Answer (score 3):

PROBLEM SOLVED, it was BIOS related (appears BIOS screen is skipped if rebooted with 5min of shut down). Changed boot sequence from Floppy,HDD to CDROM,HDD. Rebooted with NO CD in drive (GRUB not updated),keyboard now works at GRUB screen so can access all options. Now realise that I changed backup coin cell on motherboard around time I installed OpenOffice, suspect this changed boot sequence to default and somehow affected keyboard. Have compared current & previous grub.cfg – identical. Now have boot-repair disk ready for any future issues.

Comment: Thanks, changing boot sequence to ubuntu solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

*TL;DR. Try all your USB ports including all USB ports on your docking station if you have one.*

I just experienced the same thing with a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS and a following dist-upgrade now running the following:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (*lsb_release -a*)
- 3.16.0-33-generic (*uname -r*)
- grub-install (GRUB) 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1 (*grub-install --version*)

The keyboard worked the first times I booted to GRUB so I could boot Windows 8.1 as well but then it suddenly stopped working without any good reason I thought. Just like OP I could use my keyboard in BIOS and USB Legacy keyboard was already enabled so no luck there. Finally I found a PS/2 keyboard which worked in GRUB menu and I could stop the countdown timer. I now tested my USB keyboard in all USB ports on my laptop and in the docking station and it only works with GRUB in **one** USB port.

Looking back at this of course there was a good explanation. I had moved my desk just after doing my dist-upgrade and had disconnected all cables while doing the move and then reconnected the keyboard to wrong USB port.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I will plug a new, USB accessory into each USB port when I first get it. 

I'm told (at least for Windows and its bootloader) each driver install is unique to one, single USB port; it's not a _plug-once-then-have-it-apply-to-all USB ports_ approach--dumb, if that's true, but it is what it is.

I'd like to know if each instance of each USB port's driver install uses HD space, or if, following each driver install, logical links are made and substituted, pointing to one, single driver for that version of the driver. I'm not savvy enough to answer that.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I had the boot set to "fast" which it would boot up faster, but in doing that, it didn't allow my keyboard to work in dual boot when I would turn on my laptop from shutdown. It would only work right going into ubuntu (obviously when keyboard doesn't work) and/or rebooting which brings back to dual-boot main screen setup. I loaded the default settings which set boot to "normal" and this solved it for me for those that who might be stuck and a last resort before doing a Ubuntu re-install. Hope this helps.

Comment: how did you  load default settings without entering the bios?

Answer (score 3):

Turn off the fast boot in the BIOS (it worked for me).

When I hover to fast boot it says something like, fast boot is for minimizing device input for making the load faster or something, so when I turn off the fast boot, save the changes, and restart my laptop it works!

Answer (score 1):

My USB-Keyboard Coolermaster Quickfire TK was not responding in Grub2 (or at least making strange inputs like a,e,3 were possible, but on wrong buttons). Another usb- keyboard worked fine.

My solution was to turn the Keyboard itself into **6KRO** Mode instead of NKRO Mode by pressing "6" and "ESC".

Answer (score 1):

If "fast boot" is causing the problem but you don't want to turn it off, change "USB Support" from "Partial Initial" to "Full Initial" in the BIOS if there is such an option (at least at my GIGABYTE BIOS). This activates all USB devices before OS boot.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to second what [Pablo Bianchi](https://askubuntu.com/users/349837/pablo-bianchi) said. Even though USB Legacy boot =>[ENABLE] it had the problem with grub menu. changing it to USB Legacy boot =>[AUTO] solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and it turned out my mouse was somehow prohibiting the keyboard input. I unplugged it and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried enabling and disabling the BIOS keyboard support, didn't work. (Yes, keyboard works with the BIOS but not GRUB, but does work immediately after GRUB menu using CTRL-ALT-DLT to halt the boot process). 
While searching I saw someone else said about trying all USB ports. I remembered that the previous week I had moved the keyboard from one USB port to another to make space for a larger USB dongle to be plugged into a nearby USB port. So I moved the keyboard back to the USB port it was in previously and it works.
Apparently on this Dell SC440, only some USB ports work with GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was resolved by using a USB2 slot (removing from USB3 slot).

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Dell XPS 15 9550 with latest BIOS/UEFI 1.14.0) was because I added a USB-C dongle between the keyboard and the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

In my case GRUB by default only respond to "Enter" key only.
HOwever if press right Ctrl 5-6 times - grub starts respond to every key.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but none of the above helped. In my case I had to enable the BIOS option "use USB in DOS".

Answer (score -1):

Mine wouldn't work, In the Award Cmos Setup Utility, I changed first boot device to HDD and the other two disabled, and enabled USB keyboard and mouse, hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In my case there was Keyboard and mouse disabled in BIOS. Could look for this in the future.