# Keyboard is no longer responsive on grub dual boot menu load

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

don't know exactly what happened. I wasn't using ubuntu 22.04 lts for some time and after an automatic update the keyboard doesn't respond in grub menu. Ubuntu is the first boot option and Windows 10 is bootable from this menu too. Was doing some research but didn' find a clue. Someone could help me? I need to use both OS and would like to use the menu as usual. Thank you in advance.

Comment: see this answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/423036/grub-not-responding-to-keyboard