# Ubuntu 20.04 not booting after upgrading from 18.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Ubuntu 20.04 not booting after upgrading from 18.04 on my dell vostro 460 pc. I updated it sucessfully and it booted, but the keyboard was unresponsive during the dual boot. So I tried to update the grub from the terminal. After that I restarted and it is not booting instead showing a black screen with a - (hyphen) blinking. I tried to repair the boot using a live usb and used this code in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Still the problem is not resolved.

edit: This also I tried to update the input devices for the keyboard issue during the dual boot

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: update your question by boot-repair report please

Comment: what is the result of ```boot-repair```?

Comment: The `boot-repair` went well

Answer (score 1):

1. choose advanced options in boot-repair
2. in grub options choose purge kernels then reibstall last kernel


   [image]

Comment: I tried this and still it is not booting

Comment: edit: This also I tried to update the input devices for the keyboard issue during the dual boot

'sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all'

Comment: can you see advanced options for ubuntu in the boot menu, if you can see this try to boot to the old kernel

Comment: Yes, I did the purge kernels option and it is still not booting

Comment: not in boot-repair i mean in boot menu

Comment: ok, yes i can see the option there, but the keyboard is not working for me when it is booting up

Comment: see this answer to solve keyboard problem https://askubuntu.com/a/820957/1698042

Comment: Keyboard issue is solved. What to do next?

Comment: try your boot menu entrys if you can not boot use boot-repair

Comment: Tried that too...still nothing

Comment: Found the issue and it is resolved. The issue is with graphics of the Nvidia package and found one solution from the dell support [link](http://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-in/000129836/ubuntu-log-in-problems-after-running-updates#Issues_after_updates)