# Boot failure in 22.04.2 after an update - can't get to login screen (just a black screen)

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 22.04.2 booting. It doesn't anymore, after a recent update.
A few weeks ago (end of June), it was doing an automatic update, then told me that I had to reboot to finish the update. Which I did.
It failed the update, never getting to the login screen. There were a lot of lines of notices scrolling up the screen, but when it stopped, I noticed some errors in GRUB. I did a lot of research, and ended up getting Boot-Repair. Running that resulted in a displayed statement that it was successful, and could now be rebooted. But this time, the scrolling message all came back again, too fast to read. But no problems with GRUB were reported. Yet I still can't get to the login screen.
What I see a black screen with a flashing cursor, reminiscent of the scene in Jurassic Park when they tried to reboot their computer. No error messages.
I then booted from a flash drive, using Ubuntu 22.04.2, so that I could look at the Linux hard drive. I saw that the directory structure looked ok, but there was a red circle with an x in it over the /root. Not entirely unexpected. Looking in /root, all I see is the /snap directory. No files. I then looked in my /home directory, and found that the files seemed to be ok, but there was an x over the /snap directory. Since the update that caused this seemed to be mostly about snap, it gives me suspicions.
Is this salvageable?

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1477293/1698042